# Is there a tutorial for Facebooker (Rails API for Facebook)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

There once was a Facebooker tutorial which was a facebook app but for the last few weeks I'm greeted with just a blank page when I go to it. Does anyone know of any good resources for getting started with the Facebooker plugin for Rails?

I was kind of surprised at how difficult it is to find this... any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several resources for FBML canvas apps including http://www.pragprog.com/titles/mmfacer and the related screencasts. These are out of date, but give you at least a good overview. You can also ask questions on the Facebooker google group.

(Note: I'm a little biased as I'm the author of the link book and the maintainer of Facebooker)

Comment: Good to hear from the maintainer of Facebooker - can you shed any light on why the tutorial link doesn't work anymore? Also there is a facebooker2 project out now (perhaps you maintain that one too) - should we be using that one instead?

Comment: The tutorial was maintained by a developer who is no longer doing facebook development. I believe he is willing to hand over the code, it just needs a maintainer.

I'm also the author of Facebooker2. I'm using it on all projects going forward. It is much smaller and more simple than the original Facebook. It does not support FBML canvas apps, but Facebook recommends that developers use IFrame canvas apps or Facebook connect apps.